.NET 8 get file back from URL stream (keeping headers and data)
I am currently reaching out to a URL to grab a file, the GET request is a responseType:  'stream' 
In my API, I need to read this "stream" into some kind of object that I can use later, but I need to access the files Headers, and be able to also access the full data (to write it out or save it).  These are PDF files if that makes a difference, but I'm just not sure what Type I should be using for such a thing.  Here's a sample of what I have, but the headers are not correct:
        private async Task<(byte[]?, HttpContentHeaders)> ReadFileData(string url)
        {
            byte[]? fileData = null;
            HttpContentHeaders headers = null;
            using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                    fileData = memoryStream.ToArray();

                    ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileData);
                    MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                    form.Add(byteContent, "files", "files");
                    headers = form.Headers;
                }
            }

            return (fileData, headers);
        }



Why can't you just do memoryStream.Position = 0; return (memoryStream, response.Headers); immediately after the await stream.CopyToAsync line? Or return (memoryStream.ToArray(), response.Headers); if you really need it as a byte array.

EDITED!!!
This is in .NET 6 maybe can help you:
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] IFormFile? file, [FromForm] string Data)
        {
             MemoryStream requestImageStream = new MemoryStream();
                
                _requestImage.CopyTo(requestImageStream);
    
                requestImageStream.Position = 0;
        }

I use angular, so I sent the file with a FormData object in the body of the request, if you are using JavaScript you can do the same, remember do not send the header Content-Type

HttpPostedFile isn't an option in .NET 8, sorry I'll edit my original with my version

I did edit my answer, you can check it again

I don't think you need to create a MultipartFormDataContent to extract headers. You can directly access the HttpResponseMessage.Headers and HttpContent.Headers. Try them and see if you get the correct headers.
